# why $2\int_{0}^{1}xe^{iux^2}dx= \operatorname{sinc}(\frac{u}{2})$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

$2\int_{0}^{1}xe^{iux^2}dx=  \operatorname{sinc}(\frac{u}{2})= \frac{\sin(u/2)}{u/2}$
When reading some papers I always meet this kind of expansion. But I cannot understand it. May anyone here help me please?

Comment: As @HenryLee noted, it should be $\frac{e^{iu}-1}{iu}=e^{iu/2}\operatorname{sinc}\frac{u}{2}$, but the context in which you saw this discussed might not care about the phase.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=2\int_0^1xe^{iux^2}dx$$
Now make the substitution $v=iux^2$ so $dx=\frac{dv}{2iux}$ giving:
$$I=\frac{1}{iu}\int_0^{iu}e^vdv=\frac{e^{iu}-1}{iu}=\frac{\sin(u)-i\cos(u)+i}{u}$$